# How to reduce size of JPEG Image in Android

Tags: android, image, encoding, compression, jpeg

In my application, I am invoking the camera application and taking a picture and saving it in a particular directory (E.g. /sdcard etc)

The picture is saved as a JPEG image. How do I reduce the size of the image? Is there any available image encoder or compression available?

I came across another posting at:
[Android Reduce Size Of Camera Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757341/android-reduce-size-of-camera-picture)

But this is scaling the image. I am looking for something that can compress or encode. Is it possible?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943016/android-how-to-compress-or-downsize-an-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464062/compress-image-in-android

Comment: [Take a look from this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081008/outofmemoryerror-in-game-with-many-small-images/10086141#10086141

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure anyway you can try this one.For reducing the size of the image first you should convert the image to bitmap before saving it to the particular directory, and compress the bitmap set the quality of the image and write it to the correct path.The quality of the image can be changed and hope this will help you to reduce the size of the image.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);`
```

[API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29):

```
compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)
```

Comment: @faisal1208 100 means best quality.

Answer (score 1):

May be the below piece of code is useful for you

```
        opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        opt.inSampleSize = 4;
        opt.outWidth = 640;
        opt.outHeight = 480;
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeStream(in, new Rect(), opt);
        Bitmap map = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 100, 100, true);
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(map);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bao);
        ba = bao.toByteArray();
        imagedata=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

Comment: This is really late but can you please help me understand this? What is 'ba'?

Comment: ba refers to ByteArray

Answer (score 0):

Using Glide inspired by this writeup

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Gilde API

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/

```
// using some options for JPEG
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
                        .encodeFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                        .override(1280, 1024) // this is what you need to take care of WxH
                        .fitCenter(); // or centerCrop
// uri may be local or web url anything
Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(uri).apply(myOptions).listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        showSnackBar("There was some error in fetching images");
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        // do whatever with the bitmap object here
                        return true;
                    }
                }).submit();
```