# How to Compress captured image to a specific size in Android?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, image-compression

I am capturing images using my Android camera, but the camera is 8 MP, so i get around 4-5 MB jpeg images. So, I tried to compress them down to 1 MB using the following code.

**data** contains the the image in **jpeg** and **baos** is of **ByteArrayOutputStream** type.

```
while ( data.length > 1 * 1024  * 1024 )
{
    System.gc();
    Log.e(TAG,"Data size "+ (data.length/1024));
    bitmapData.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, compressionRatio, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
    Log.e(TAG,"Data size "+ (data.length/1024));
    compressionRatio -= 5 ;
}
```

It allows me to capture a few images but after a a couple of pics, the application crashes with error log `Out of memory`.
Can any one please provide a better solution to compress a JPEG.

ThankYou

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943016/android-how-to-compress-or-downsize-an-image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265008/how-to-reduce-large-image-size-to-thumbnail-size-in-android

Comment: just use  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

Comment: In the first two solutions I wont get the final size of the JPEG image. So, I cannot compress based on the size of the .jpeg . While in the solution by @SubbaReddyPolamReddy writing to the external storage device will take very long and slow down the proess.

Comment: u use device or eclipse... it doesn't slow...

Comment: Can't you choose a smaller picture size? Your 8MP camera definitely supports 1600×1200 px

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the solution you provided is that the bitmap is allocating all the memory. What you need to do is add this to the end of your loop.

```
bitmapData.recycle();
System.gc();
```

This marks the bitmap as dead and ready for garbage collecting, and manually calls the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but i hope this helps somebody.Adding this code to start of loop will reset byteArrayOutputStream(baos):

```
baos.reset();
```